# Overlapping of fragments when transiting on clicking on an item in RecyclerView of one fragment to another new fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-recyclerview, overlapping

I am new to android development. The problem is the RecyclerView populated using a firebase database is not replaced by a new fragment, rather the new fragment is on top, but clicking on another item of the recycler view still works, which I checked using a toast in the new fragment. I know that the next fragment is there because I have TextView at the bottom, which is visible on clicking on the recycler view Item.

Here is my code

```
adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Categories, CategoryViewHolder>(options) {

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final CategoryViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Categories model)
            {

                Picasso.get().load(model.getImage()).placeholder(R.drawable.camera).into(holder.categoryImage, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess()
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

                holder.categoryName.setText(model.getName());
                holder.categoryImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), holder.categoryName.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ProductListActivity.class);
//                        startActivity(intent);
                        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) view.getContext();

                        SearchFragment fragment = SearchFragment.newInstance(holder.categoryName.getText().toString());
                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, fragment, SearchFragment.class.getSimpleName());
                        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    }
                });
```

The fragment I am using is also used for the navigation drawer using navController.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit**: I have another recyclerView inside SearchFragment, which didn't show after I clicked an image in the RecyclerView(One which calls SearchFragment). But it showed after I minimized and opened the app again. I don't understand why that is happening.

Comment: try adding "android:clickable=true" on the xml of the new fragment, so that it will capture all clilcks and the Android OS won't send them back to the old fragment below. hope this helps :)

Comment: Still no luck, The SearchFragment details are displayed along with the recycler view of the previous fragments. The images onClick are working and I am sure of that because I am displaying the argument that I sent to SearchFragment on the screen and it still changes when I click on images in the recycler view, it is like both the fragments are active simultaneously.
I am still very new to android, but do I need to add the SearchFragment in the navigation graph and connect the two fragments???

Answer (score 0):

I just found an easy way to move from one fragment to another without using FragmentManager. I hope this helps others, it worked for me. Initialize the NavController in the first fragment inside onCreateView

```
navController = Navigation.findNavController(getActivity(), R.id.nav_host_fragment);
```

And adding the following for transition

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putString("Category", holder.categoryName.getText().toString());

 navController.navigate(R.id.nav_category_product_list, bundle);
```

to get the argument in the moving fragment type this

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);  //To get menu items at the top
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            Category = getArguments().getString("Category");
        }
    }
```

Also, add this transition in Navigation graph XML

```
.
.
.
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_category"
        android:name="com.grocery.admin.ui.category.CategoryFragment"
        android:label="@string/menu_category"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_category" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_nav_category_to_nav_category_product_list"
            app:destination="@id/nav_category_product_list" />
    </fragment>

<fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_category_product_list"
        android:name="com.grocery.admin.ui.category.CategoryProductFragment"
        android:label="Product List"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_category_product">
</fragment>
.
.
.
```